# How to define association between two model in cakephp 2.8.0

Tags: cakephp

I have two model user and project and user_id is stored in project table how to implement inner join to display user name for users tables and projects table all fields.
     this is my model for defining association
    // project model

```
class Project extends AppModel 
{
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
public $hasOne= array('User');
}
//Query Is
   $conetent= $this->Project->find('all',array('limit' => 3,'joins' => array(array('table' => 'users','alias' => 'User1','type' => 'INNER','conditions' => array('Project.user_id =User1.id')))));
```

Comment: I am also looking for something where I could fetch the cities associated with a particular state or county after making any selection from state/county dropdown. Is it a kind of association or some join I should use? Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1):

Best to do using cakephp way.
Add following code to your project controller.
  $conetent= $this->Project->find('all',array('limit' => 3,'contain' => array('User')));

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a belongsTo relationship. This way, when you do a find in the Projects controller, it will pull the appropriate record from the User table that the project belongs to. For example (using CakePHP 2.x)

**Database Tables**

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(96) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastlogin` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `projects` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Users Controller**

```
class UsersController extends AppController {
    public $uses = array('User');

    public function index() {

    }

    public function create() {

    }

    public function update() {

    }

    public function delete() {

    }
}
```

**Users Model**

```
<?php

class User extends AppModel {

}
```

Projects Controller

```
<?php

class ProjectsController extends AppController {
    public $uses = array('Project');
    public $components = array('Paginator', 'RequestHandler');

    public function index() {
        $projects = $this->Project->find('all'));
    }
}
```

Projects Model

```
<?php

class Project extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'projects';
    public $belongsTo = array('User');
}
```

The find in the projects controller should yield a result of something like this:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Project' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'firstname' => 'John',
            'lastname' => 'Smith',
            'email' => 'john.smith@domain.tld',
            'password' => '******',
            'created' => '2016-10-06 00:00:00',
            'modified' => '2016-10-06 00:00:00',
            'lastlogin' => '2016-10-06 00:00:00'
        ),
        'User' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'user_id' => '1',
            'name' => 'Project Name',
            'description' => 'Project Description',
            'created' => '2016-10-06 00:00:00',
            'modified' => '2016-10-06 00:00:00'
        )
    )
)
```